# Remote connections between Linux machines in general

Tags: networking

I'd like to learn how to establish connections between different Linux machines. For example, transferring files from one Ubuntu 18.04 to another inside a WiFi network, or maybe sharing my friend's desktop to my home PC so I could help him fix something. But I don't know what exactly should I learn, and thus don't know what kind of tutorials or something should I search. Please, provide some information so I would at least know what area should I search in.

Comment: If I want to transfer files (irregularly) I use `scp` (secure [encrypted] version of 'remote copy` or rcp). When accessing files from a server, my default choice is `nfs` (network file system) though for I once used samba (smb or cifs) which is easier with some OSes. In many cases though, your intended use will dictate which is best.

Comment: Sharing screen `TeamViewer`, share files via wifi network `scp`, or `rsync` will do, or mount remote file location with `sshfs`, `CIFS`, `Samba` etc

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so general to answer however there is a lot of way to transferring data in network. It also depends on what type of data you are going to transfer.
In nutshell for transferring file you need setup *FTP* server which most favorite FTP server in Linux is `VSFTP` , you can install it on Ubuntu by :

`sudo apt install vsftpd`

Also another way is transferring data over SSH. There is some favorite tools like `scp` or `rsync`which need to setup `ssh server` on both computers. Moreover you need basic knowledge for configuring the network. Tool for configuring Ubuntu is `nmcli` and for run-time configuration `ip` command.

If there is windows system computer in network, you also can `samba` service for communicating with windows hosts but basically setting up FTP server is more desirable due to is acceptable by all of operating systems. For providing security to your FTP server you can use `chroot` in FTP configuration.

Answer (score 1):

For file transfer go for scp

```
scp <file/folder to send> <address+location to send to>
```

eg:

```
scp myTestFile Username@10.99.xx.xx:~/Desktop
```

NOTE : You need to install openssh-server to use scp service.

For having remote access to your friends system you can go for ssh :

```
ssh -X Username@10.99.xx.xx
```

Ofcourse you might need to install required packages on both the computers and might need to configure things here and there if required, but you can start with these commands.
Also, you are not limited to these methods and can go for a lot of other alternatives.